# multiple selectbox not showing even the multiple attribute

Tags: php

```
<?php
$tab=$_GET['liste'];
$max=sizeof($tab);
echo$max;
echo$_GET['type'];
if ($_GET['type']='multiple')
{
    ?>
    <form name='form'>
    <select size=<?php $max ?> multiple>
    <?php
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        echo"<option value=$i>$tab[$i]</option>";
                          }
    echo"</select>";
    echo"</form>";
}
else{
    ?>
    <form name='form'>
    <select size=<?php $max ?>>
    <?php
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        echo"<option value=$i>$tab[$i]</option>";
        }
    echo"</select>";
    echo"</form>";


}
?>
```

in two cases it's showing just the dropdown list width single choice  even if $_GET['type']='multiple' . 
I tried

```
 <select size=<?php $max ?> <?php echo$_GET['type']; ?>>
```

instead of

```
<select size=<?php $max ?> multiple>
```

But still not working !!
Any suggestions please !

Comment: its of course a multiple list. You can press 'ctrl' key and select multiple options.

Comment: Btw when you have array you can make forech not for loop..

Comment: You almost had it, but the answer said `<?=` - note the equal sign is very important here, it denotes an echo statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot that needs fixing here (no offense), so let's start with

```
if($_GET['type']='multiple')
```

All this is doing is assigning the value 'multiple' the $_GET['type'] variable, so this will always hit. Next, as mentioned before, you need to change

```
<?php $max ?>
```

as it currently does nothing. Next up is

```
echo"<option value=$i>$tab[$i]</option>";
```

When using an array element in a string, **must** be wrapped with `{` and `}`

Let's take a look at some cleaned up code because there are too many errors here to pinpoint the real issue:

```
<?php
$tab = $_GET['liste'];
$max = sizeof($tab);
#echo $max;
#echo $_GET['type'];

$multiple = '';

if($_GET['type'] == 'multiple')
{
    $multiple = ' multiple="multiple"';
}
?>

<form name='form'>
    <select size="<?php echo $max ?>" <?php echo $multiple; ?>>
    <?php
    foreach($tab as $key => $value)
        echo "<option value='{$key}'>{$value}</option>";
    ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

**Edit**: Just verified - variables inside a string must always be wrapped in `{` and `}` if it's referencing an array element (this does not apply to objects after all):

```
$a = array('foo' => 'bar');
$o = new stdclass;
$o->foo = 'bar';
$o->baz = array('foo' => 'bar');

echo "$a['foo']"; // Syntax error
echo "$o->foo"; // echos "bar"
echo "{$a['foo']}"; // echos "bar"
echo "$o->baz['foo']"; // Syntax error
```

In general, it's a Good Idea to always wrap variables in strings with `{` and `}`, even if it's legally allowed:

```
echo "Something {$here}"; // Obvious variable is obvious
```

Comment: now the select box is showing, but I can't make multiple choices.I mean (Ctrl+Click) doesn't work ?!

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<select name='ville' size="$max" multiple>
```

to

```
<select name='ville' size="<?=$max?>" multiple>
```

Comment: I noticed you changed it to size=<?php $max ?>, but this will not help. It needs to be size="<?php echo $max ?>" or size="<?=$max?>". Notice the quote marks and the echo statement (either as echo or = sign)

Comment: the problem is not in here i have the problem in multiple

Comment: You are leaving out the quotes and the echo statement. Phatskat said the same thing. You have to have both the quotes around it and the = or echo statement inside.

Comment: Technically it *should* work without quotes, but it's a good thing to do so you don't end up with some values going all over the place and running into each other.

Comment: Oh, good point, its a number. The real error was not having echo or =